# Применение Smarty в своих скриптах

Tags: лицензирование, smarty

Привет всем!
Можно-ли применять Smarty в своих некоммерческих скриптах? Если да то на каких условиях? [Здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_LGPL) куча всего и просто непонятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть [такой сайт](https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-lesser-general-public-license-v2.1-(lgpl-2.1)), он еще в альфе, но уже говорит о том, что можно distribute и modify - то есть можно изменять и распространять при условии приложения оригинальной лицензии, указания на то, что данная работа включает в себя лицензируемое ПО smarty и ссылку на исходный код smarty.

Беглый гуглеж сказал, что главная цель (L)GPL - заставить использующих данный опенсорсный софт также свободно распространять полученный продукт.

upd [вот еще](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/) один аналогичный сайт

Comment: "при условии приложения оригинальной лицензии, указания на то, что данная работа включает в себя лицензируемое ПО smarty и ссылку на исходный код smarty." это означает что надо делать сноску, что использую ПО smarty, в комментариях в каждом файле?!

Comment: @vp111, нет, достаточно один раз "явно" приложить лицензию и уведомление о наличии смарти в программе.

> a) Give prominent notice with each copy of the Combined Work that the Library is used in it and that the Library and its use are covered by this License.

Если приложение показывает копирайт-нотисы, то они должны включать в себя упоминание о смарти и его лицензию.

> c) For a Combined Work that displays copyright notices during execution, include the copyright notice for the Library among these notices, as well as a reference directing the user to the copies of the GNU GPL and this licens

Comment: "явно" приложить лицензию - это, как я понимаю, добавить файл COPYING.lib из Smarty-3.1.19.zip? а уведомление о наличии смарти в программе - это сделать файл license.html и там сделать сноску что моя программа состоит из библиотеки смарти и т.п.?

Comment: @vp111,  к использованию чего-либо в некоммерческих скриптах (также как и своих скриптов другими людьми) можно относиться и не столь щепетильно.

Упомяните где-нибудь в комментариях, да и ладно... 

Free оно и есть free.

Comment: @vp111, про текст лицензии я кажется соврал (хотя не будет ничего страшного, если он будет включен). Достаточно будет указать в каком-нибудь LICENSE.md, что данное ПО, %имя% распространяется по такой-то лицензии (текст ниже) и включает в себя: смарти - лицензия LGPL, дамби - лицензия WTFPL, и так далее. Если выводится где-то "пакет такой-то, 2014, разработчик А.Б.Вгдейкин" - то туда же просто добавляем "с использованием смарти" со ссылкой на сайт/репу смарти.